# Linear Taylor Polynomials about 0

Tags: taylor-expansion

(a) Find the linear Taylor polynomial about $0$ for $(1 + x)^{15}$

For the first question I tried to use the formula: $1 + px + p\frac{(p-1)}{2!}  x^2$

This didn't work for me as when I substituted $x$ (part b) I only got 4 decimal digits.

---

(b) Use the linear Taylor polynomial to find the associated remainders when $x = 0.01$
and $x = 0.1.$ Give these associated remainders to six decimal places.

I'm guessing part (b) will be simply putting the $x$ values into the equation and part (c) will be obvious when part (b) is answered.

---

(c) Compare the remainders obtained in (b). What conclusions can you draw?

Answer (score 0):

The taylor series is given by:
$$(1+x)^{15}=1+15x+R(x),$$
where $R(x)$ is the remainder.  The Lagrange form of the remainder is given by:
$$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1},$$ where $c$ is some number between $a$ and $x$. Here $a=0$ and $n=1$ so we have:
$$R_1(x)=\frac{f^{''}(c)}{2!}x^{2}=\frac{105c^2}{2!}x^{2}.$$

Substitute the appropriate values of $x$ and and the error.